# Can not open jupyter notebook in localhost in ubuntu

Tags: python, browser, jupyter-notebook, localhost

I didn't run jupyter notebook for a long time, Today when I try to launch to notebook , I can't run it and I encountered this: 
[image]

```
[I 19:05:29.939 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 19:05:29.939 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 19:05:29.939 NotebookApp] http://localhost:9999/
[I 19:05:29.939 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
Opening in existing browser session.
```

Then can not open in browser. I looked up other similar question but I didn't find to solution.

Comment: What happens when you open http://localhost:9999/?

Comment: Loading... with progress

Comment: Are you running this on dokcer or virtualbox ?

Comment: No , I was running on my host.

Comment: better try reinstalling jupyter then.